# Книги для создания децентрализованных приложений/криптовалют

Tags: криптография, книги

Для опыта и интереса хочу изучить тему децентрализованных приложений и создания криптовалют. Какие языки программирования для этого используются и какие книги(желательно на русском) я могу прочитать?